# Newtonsoft.Json.Schema support string or null

Tags: json.net, jsonschema

I am using **Json.Net 7.0.1**
I have a schema that works great with definitions for properties like this:

```
"phone":{"type":"string", "required":false}
```

However when I try to do this:

```
"phone":{"type":["string", "null"], "required":false}
```

I get an exception that type cannot convert an array to a nullable type. I can see that this is happening because type is being converted to an enum value in C#.

How do I support null or string using **Newtonsoft.Json.Schema**?

Also one more thing: I tried the Json.NET Schema package, but it won't run. Even though it says it needs Netwonsoft.Json >= 6.0.8 it throws an error at runtime that it can't find the Json.Net library if I use the new JSchema.

Comment: I got my answer, and not one I like:
Since it is an enum I took a look at it and the values are this:
public enum JsonSchemaType {
    None = 0,
    String = 1,
    Float = 2,
    Integer = 4,
    Boolean = 8,
    Object = 16,
    Array = 32,
    Null = 64,
    Any = 127,}
I noticed it is a bitflag enum, and that Any is 127 (all the others), so I tried the numeric value 65:
“type”:65
And that worked. It is not as easily readable as [“string”, “null”], but at least it works.

Comment: Did you try using a comma separated string value format like `"type":"String, Null"` (no array brackets)?  I'm guessing it might work since that is the string representation of a flags enum value with multiple flags set.

Comment: I don't know the lib used, but **WHY** do you want to allow `null` on a non-required property?  It is much cleaner to remove the property than to set it to `null`.

Comment: Thank you Brian, I will try that, I am new to JSON and didn't know that was the way you represent bit flag enums.

Fiddur, I am not in control of the input:
    <attribute missing>, 
    "attribute":,
    "attribute":null.
I don't want the validator to fail any of these. I think this is pretty normal.
If I were allowing patch the null and empty are very useful. If it is not there I don't overwrite that property, if it is null or empty (i.e. attribute is there with no value) I would overwrite with the null or empty.